# Automating Git & SSH workflow

Tags: macos, git, ssh, automation, workflow

I'm working on a programming project with a few team members, using Git for version control. Every hour I have to deploy a live version of our repository for others to preview. This involves the following commands:

```
ssh me@mywebsite.com 
cd /path/to/my/preview
git checkout develop
git pull
```

As you can imagine, this task becomes tedious with repetition. **What's the best way to automate this process?** The ideal solution would be some sort of script or icon on my desktop that I can click to make the magic happen. I am using **Mac OSX**, so maybe the *Automator* application is a possibility.

**Note:** I have already established password-free SSH logins between my computer and the remote server (using a shared key).

Comment: You could write a bash script for it.

Comment: [This](http://superuser.com/a/355030) looks like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would take a look at [fabric](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.8/) for that.

Or, there's also [capistrano](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki), which I like quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use python "paramiko" module to automate this workflow.
Paramiko has support for ssh and you can execute git commands after u login to the remote system using python script.
Documentation:
https://docs.paramiko.org/en/stable/api/channel.html